# quadratic equation problem.

Tags: roots, quadratics

I have been fumbling for months now to acquire the solution.
My previous question was unclear, sorry for that.

$$\large 2^{x/2}+3^{x/2}=13^{x/4}$$

Please try to solve it.

Thanks in advance!!!

Comment: The answer is 4.

Comment: can you please show the process @DiegoMath

Comment: Can you please write what have tried?

Comment: I am not able to find the value of x in the above equation @Nilknarf

Comment: Hint: substitute $t$ for $\frac{x}{4}$ in the answer below.

Comment: your hint is nice!!!

Comment: I am not able to think from where I should start from but I tried expressing 13 as (3*3+2*2 )  @DiegoMath

Comment: cant understand though!!please help@Theta

Comment: @DibyaranjanMishra It is advisable to get rid of square roots, therefore make use of Dr. Sonnhard Graubner's answer below, substitute $t$ for $\frac{x}{4}$ and see what you get.

Comment: @MANMAID yes I know

Comment: @DibyaranjanMishra take $\sin t=4/\sqrt{13}$.

Comment: @MANMAID this idea does not work

Comment: The title is misleading. This isn't a quadratic equation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Our question:

> To find $t$, such that $4^t+9^t=13^t$

$(\frac{4}{13})^t+(\frac{9}{13})^t=1$. Note that $t=1$ is trivial solution.

$\frac{4}{13},\frac{9}{13}<1$. Then, if $t>1$, $(\frac{4}{13})^t<\frac{4}{13}$. Similarly $(\frac{9}{13})^t<\frac{9}{13}$. So $(\frac{4}{13})^t+(\frac{9}{13})^t<(\frac{4}{13})+(\frac{9}{13})=1$.(Why?)

if $0<t<1$, $(\frac{4}{13})^t>\frac{4}{13}$. Similarly $(\frac{9}{13})^t>\frac{9}{13}$. So $(\frac{4}{13})^t+(\frac{9}{13})^t>(\frac{4}{13})+(\frac{9}{13})=1$.(Why?)

Hence $t=1$ is only solution.

**Note:** If you do not understand "Why" part, comment please. I will edit the post.

Answer (score 4):

HINT: write your equation in the form
$$2^{x/2}+3^{x/2}=13^{x/4}$$
and $$4^t+9^t=13^t$$ from the hint above!

Comment: I substituted x/2 as t then what should I do??

Comment: sere this in my post!

Comment: after that... I may be sounding foolish but I am in std 9 and this topic is being done for first time.so sorry for in convenience

Comment: it doesn't matter but we all here to help you!

Comment: ok so how could i solve  the equation cause its not in the standard form

Answer (score 1):

Hint:  by inspection $x=4$ is a solution, then show that $\displaystyle\left(\frac{2}{\sqrt{13}}\right)^{x/2}+\left(\frac{3}{\sqrt{13}}\right)^{x/2}$
 is strictly decreasing, so $x=4$ is the only solution.